# SASS inadvertently unencdoding URL-Strings

Tags: css, angular, svg, sass, internet-explorer-11

I'm using SASS in an Angular CLI project, trying to use a URL-Encoded SVG with some style information as a background image.

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1' width='600' height='600' viewBox='0 0 1 1'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E.cls-1 %7B fill: %23005680; %7D%3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg fill='%231e1916'%3E%3Cpath class='cls-1' d='M.73555824.90496726l-.0048958.00070358L.7259425.90628648l-.004544.00049838-.0043388.0003811-.00422154.00029317-.00401633.0001759-.00386973.00008794H.70122895L.6976817.90760572.694281.9074005.6910269.90710734.6879194.90672624.68492913.90622783l-.00281435-.000557L.67941768.9050259.67686718.904293.67443394.90347212l-.002316-.0009088-.0021694-.00099676L.6678671.9005112.6659322.89936786.6640853.89813658.66235564.89684666.66074326.8954688.65921882.8940323.65781162.89250787.6564924.8909248.65526112.88928306.65411778.88755343.6530624.88576513.6512155.88201266l-.00155376-.003987L.64840112.8738041.64737506.86937737.6465835.8647161.64602653.8598789.64561608.85486585.64535223.84967686.64520566.844312.64517636.83882986l.0000586-.0056287L.6452936.82745517.64541086.82162125.64555746.8096016l.0000293-.00609777L.63916652.66785768.61243013.79309656C.60680142.81631502.6004691.83812628.63424138.855716.65816343.876853.63142704.90570016.60539423.9021822.52729583.90496727.53855325.85293097.54558915.81631503l.00422152-.0534728L.5624753.6537859.55192145.6263459C.46678716.60453465.40909283.5883521.34365903.55317262l-.0464369.00633232C.27541088.56302287.2810396.5876485.27892882.60383106L.27189293.6481865l-.0386974.10061326-.00281435.00841376C.2275668.76424942.2282704.79168938.23812064.80576118l.02110768.04224467C.2747073.87119498.27892882.93029645.2353063.91129957h.00070358l-.0323651-.0133682C.18042632.8881104.16142942.8240838.15298635.7776469l.00140718-.0661667C.13398943.7058808.12554636.8233509.13398943.84800584l.0204041.06118294C.16002223.9288893.1368038.9359545.12062123.9359545c-.0379938 0-.05487995-.03872673-.06261943-.07109183L.0523731.84023704C.04252282.80294682.04744795.7459561.06644487.7128874L.0762951.6924833C.09247767.65167513.07137.62282796.0664449.6017203.0502623.5355829.03689412.4715563.08262742.40823326L.08684895.40333744C.0847382.398383.07137.38785848.0636305.36320354.0460408.3069164.0305618.2147462.0523731.2147462L.06714845.2140426c.03658664 0 .0253292.1519753.06965534.14212504L.45341896.3596856.5097061.34423593C.5294066.3385779.54699633.3259133.56528964.31465588L.6018763.29214102C.64268445.3336528.6792711.3596856.7390762.38149685.75525873.50532857.7369654.53279785.72148645.6066454l-.0056287.03025436C.70389672.68969826.70037877.7445489.70319313.79942886L.7046003.8247581c-.00140716.0260328.0140718.02817288.0344759.0345052.0133682.00700657.02251485.03303937-.00351796.04570398h.00070358-.00070358zM.8031028.14649805L.8046859.1476707l.0016417.00117264.00331273.00255052.00343.0027264.00348862.0029023.00354726.0030489.0035766.00316615.0036352.00328342.00366454.00337137L.83464706.173381l.00366452.00351795.0072411.0072118.00354727.0036352.00351795.0036352.00343.0036059.00334204.0036059L.8819048.2224857c.0140718.01477536.03588306.0126646.05487996.01688613l.0077395.0007036c.02040407.01128673.01407178.0338016.00703588.0506584L.9473386.301317C.92693452.34983533.86783302.35335328.82561766.33083844L.80732436.32098818H.80099203l-.0133682.00844308-.0260328.021137C.7067111.3266462.66238495.2984733.6272055.2604795L.70882184.1577555l.02743997-.039401.00562873-.0133682.0063323-.01474606S.77355207.0585494.78832745.0648817C.8031028.0712433.81224947.09865397.80873152.11272575L.80451.1296119.8031028.14649806h.0007036'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

but this is what I get returned by the server:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1' width='600' height='600' viewBox='0 0 1 1'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E.cls-1{fill:%23005680}%3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cpath class='cls-1' d='M.736.905H.73L.726.907H.72L.717.908H.685L.682.905.68.905H.677L.674.902H.672L.67.902.668.9.666.899H.664L.662.896.661.895.659.894.658.893.656.89V.889L.653.888V.886L.65.882.65.878.648.874V.869L.646.865.646.86V.804L.639.668.612.793C.607.816.6.838.634.856c.024.02-.003.05-.029.046C.527.905.54.852.545.816L.55.763l.012-.11-.01-.027A.85.85 0 0 1 .344.553L.297.56C.275.563.281.588.28.604L.272.648l-.039.1-.003.01a.072.072 0 0 0 .008.048L.26.848C.275.871.28.93.235.911h.001L.204.898C.18.888.16.824.153.778L.154.71C.134.706.126.823.134.848l.02.061C.16.93.137.936.121.936.083.936.066.897.058.865L.052.84A.193.193 0 0 1 .066.713l.01-.02C.092.651.071.622.066.601.05.536.036.472.083.408L.087.403C.085.398.07.388.064.363.046.307.03.215.052.215L.067.214c.037 0 .025.152.07.142L.453.36.51.344C.53.34.547.326.565.314L.602.293c.04.042.077.068.137.09.016.123-.002.15-.018.225l-.005.03a.598.598 0 0 0-.013.162l.002.026C.703.85.719.853.739.859.752.866.762.892.736.905zM.803.146l.002.002h.001L.81.152l.003.003.004.003L.82.16l.004.003.003.004.004.003.004.003.003.004.008.007.003.004.004.003.003.004.003.004.023.023C.896.237.918.235.937.24L.945.24c.02.011.014.034.007.05L.947.302C.927.35.867.353.826.331L.807.32H.801L.788.329.762.351A.389.389 0 0 1 .627.26L.71.157l.027-.04.006-.013L.748.09S.774.06.788.065c.015.006.024.034.02.048L.806.13.803.146' fill='%231e1916'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
```

Notice that there's a "charset" being added and - more problematic - the braces of the style have been decoded:

```
.cls-1{fill:%23005680}
```

This still works for modern browsers, but not for IE11 (which is a requirement for my project).

How do I prevent SASS from touching these URLs altogether?

Comment: What happens with IE11? Tested with IE11, Edge and Chrome, everything seems to be working with the css you provided.

Comment: I don't see anything with IE11 (Windows 10 Creators Update) - have you tested the second background-image-code?